# What is the best model to catch DB side error?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, database, web-applications

We have a web application that all update, insert and DB operation procedure handle via SQL Server DB 2017. What is the best way to handle and get error (in Web-app or SQL server error handler?). for example a foreign key error occurred, is it better to handle it via DB or Code?

Update 1: 
for all operation from server side we have a procedure in DB. when user ran into error, handle of this error should be in DB or not (is it good architecture, or what is the pros and cons).

Update 2:

```
BEGIN TRY
  -- do something, eg.
  INSERT INTO tabel1 (id, name) VALUES (10, 'sample data');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  THROW;
END CATCH
```

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering Stack Exchange... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: can you add a bit about your concerns with each approach?

Comment: add an example procedure

Comment: @Ewan see updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors tend to be unhandleable. In the sense that there's no automatic remedy you can apply. You simply have to log them and present the user with a friendly error message.

As such the **Data layer** should:

1. Throw an exception,
2. Let it bubble up to the application layer

the **Application Layer** should:

1. Log the detailed error
2. Create a "friendly error message" for the user to see
3. Send the "friendly error message" to the user

Attempting to handle the error in the SQL, other than general use of transactions and rollbacks is unhelpful because:

1. Creation of the "Friendly Message" is business logic. The general rule is to avoid putting business Logic in the database. Because it lowers performance
2. Logging requires the full error message. Having your database write to a log file would be problematic and non performant

Comment: My concern is which one is better from performance or easiness?  would you please describe a bit more?

Comment: for all operation from server side we have a procedure in DB. when user ran into error, handle of this error should be in DB or not?

Comment: you should prob add these comments, with more detail about what you tried and why it worries you, more about the nature of your application and the errors that are occuring etc to your question

Comment: I update my question. please help me to improve

Comment: I read your answer carefully, you means error should handle in DB and send result to business logic for error friendly message, you means if we didnt pass the error to business logic the performance is more better? am I right?

Comment: @MounaMokhiab no, the opposite. _dont_ handle in SQL

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstanding, would you please say a short sentence in a simpler way why don't? I couldn't get the point. I think you wrote your answer very professionally.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but is english your first language? I could try and translate to another language if required

Comment: please don't laugh to me (English is second). this sentence confused me. "Creation of the "Friendly Message" is business logic, may require translations etc and will lower performance of your DB" this is my problem ? business logic means application?

Comment: I was thinking I could run any problem phrases through google translate and back to see if they make sense in your first language. I will try and rephrase that sentance

Comment: very niec. I accept it but please take some minutes to improve and generalize your answer (use simpler)for anyone that not professional. thanks.

Comment: I have tried to clear it up a bit. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

By far the most important part of **Structured Exception Handling** is the *last* part - the *Handling*.

Catch Exceptions where you can do something *useful* with/about them.

Ideally, that would be to take some corrective action, make the problem "go away" and then the caller never knows anything about it.

There is nothing the database can do to *correct* a Foreign Key error; indeed, it's the database that's *raising* the error, to tell the Application about the problem!

Agreed, logging Exceptions *can* be useful for diagnostic purposes, but it's better to let the client Application do that, because it will enrich the database error with contextual information of its own, for example, where in the program the failure occurred.

There are two kinds of Catch block that you should *never* write and you've demonstrated one of them:

- Catch and do nothing.  Never catch an Exception and do nothing at all with it.  The Exception will be "swallowed" without trace by such a construct, potentially masking a much larger problem.
- Catch and [only] rethrow.  Never catch an Exception and simply rethrow the same Exception.  Not only is it not "useful", but it defeats the purpose of **Structured** Exception Handling, where the Exception can propagate as far as it likes up the call stack until it finds something or someone that *can* handle it.  Also, in many languages, throwing Exceptions is expensive (that "search" for a relevant handling routine *can* be slow!).  That's not to say that you shouldn't catch an Exception and throw a *different* one at a "process boundary", say, at in a Public method of a shared library but, as a rule, no.

Comment: nice answer. but not clear me really which one is better?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the database can "self-correct" errors, especially those that it has just thrown.  As such, there is no benefit in catching them at the database level.  Let them percolate up into the client application where you can do something "useful" with them.